# How to pre-fill a field in a ModelForm with the field's default value and not include it in the form itself

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a **Post** model which has a field called **author**, I was able to set the current user as it's default, But when I'm trying to not include it in the **form** related to it, It fails and gives me different errors. Here's the code:
**models.py:**

```py
def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    file_extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
    return f'user_{instance.author}/{instance.pub_date.strftime("%Y/%B/%a-%M")}/logo.{file_extension}'


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    body = models.TextField()
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

**forms.py**:

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body', 'author', 'logo')

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control bg-dark border border-secondary text-light'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control bg-dark border border-secondary text-light'}),
            'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control bg-dark border border-secondary text-light'}),
            'logo': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control bg-dark border border-secondary text-light'}),
        }
```

**views.py:**

```py
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'login'
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = "posts/new_post.html"
```

How can I not include the field in the form and the page, But have it use it's own default value?
**NOTE** that I don't want to create a field and make it hidden!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe remove author from `PostForm` and in `PostCreateView`:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'login'
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = "posts/new_post.html"
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.author = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

EDIT:
I don't think that passing `get_user_model()` as default in foreginkey field will work. This method will return the currently active user model, as [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) explain, but you need as defaut user object or id, so it should be:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In that case you only need to remove field author from `PostForm`, you don't need to assign request.user in `form_valid` method of `PostCreateView`.

Comment: Or we can use settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL